# Video stops if user moves the camera away

Tags: android, vuforia

I am building and AR app with Vuforia and I have the following problem:

When I point the camera to the target, the video starts automatically (everything fine). However, if I move the camera and the target disappears from the screen, the video stop automatically and I would like it to continue.

How can I prevent videos from stopping automatically?

Comment: Post some code, it'll be complicated helping you otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can use extended tracking on your target. By doing so, 3d model or video in this case will be available regardless.